# How to receive all the records from MSSQL in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**I have a Car Model:**

```
package com.example.demo.models;

...

@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public Car(String title, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**I have a Car Repository:**

```
package com.example.demo.repositories;

...

public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, Long> {
    List<Car> findByTitle(String title);
}
```

**And I have a Controller:**

```
package com.example.demo.controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
...
import com.example.demo.models.Car;
import com.example.demo.repositories.CarRepository;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8081")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    CarRepository carRepository;

    @GetMapping("/cars")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Car>> getAllCars() {
        try {
            List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();

            carRepository.findAll().forEach(cars::add);

            if (cars.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }

            return new ResponseEntity<>(cars, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
}
```

When I accomplish **./mvnw spring-boot:run** my application starts and I can see its working at http://localhost:8080/api/cars (app returns 204 status and that's it).

Since that I go to Azure Data Studio, add a record into Cars DB table and get 500 Server Error.

**Because I'm doing it at the first time, there are triple things, which I'm concerned of:**

1. How can I deep into the reason of 500 error (I don't now how to debug Spring app).
2. Am I on the right track of getting all the records from cars table?
3. What should I do to cars table wasn't be cleared every time then app starts?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to avoid your `cars table` being re-created each time you run the app, you must specify in your `application.properties` file this line

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Also, update your question with your stacktrace (error details) when getting the `HTTP 500`

Comment: >>update your question with your stacktrace<<

It was a part of my question. I don't know, that tools should I use for this one...

Comment: Check the `run` section in your IDE. There you'll see all logs of your running app

Comment: If you mean terminal section, I see only this https://i.imgur.com/LVfvDyg.png. I illuminated strings, which appear when I reload page in a browser.